# Jackson ObjectMapper ignore lazy fields

Tags: java, spring-boot, objectmapper

I have a Spring Boot API, with JPA. Within this project, I have a class called CommunityProfile, which contains several lazy loaded fields.

I need to send this data via a webhook, and the method for sending the data should be able to work with any data. When attempting to serialize the object, I get the error:

```
Exception: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: my.package.CommunityProfile.awards: could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

My ObjectMapper class is set up as so:

```java
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        return new ObjectMapper()
                .configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false)
                .configure(SerializationFeature.)
                .registerModule(new Hibernate5Module())
                .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())
                .disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
    }
```

and my code to serialise the object is:

```java
String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(data);
```

Where `data` is an `Object` type (it can be anything).
JsonViews and JsonIgnore doesn't fit my needs, as they're already in use for other elements. Opinions appreciated.

Comment: you can get rid of the error if you specify the transactional read only in your query `@Transactional(readOnly = true)`